# How to find and replace on patterns like ‘something=“string”’ on Linux?

Tags: xml, replace, replaceall

I have an XML file in which there are tags like below.

```
<project name=“something” revision=“abc” />
<project name=“something2” revision=“xyz” />
...
```

How can I replace ‘revision=“string here”’ with my own strings on Linux (Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right tool for this job is XSLT. There's a bit of a learning curve, but it's very powerful and you should really be using XML-aware tools to process XML files (if you use non-XML-aware tools like sed, there's a great risk of producing invalid XML).

Comment: Agreed, an XSLT/XPath solution under a general purpose programming language is the better solution. And you're totally right that sed could produce invalid XML. I suggested the sed solution because the author referenced a Linux solution and didn't indicate they had access to a language. But ultimately thats the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to do the substitution in place. Lets say you wanted to replace `revision="abc"` with `revision="foobar"` the resulting command would be (assuming the XML is in a file named `foo.xml`)

```
    cat foo.xml | sed 's/revision="abc"/revision="foobar"/g'
```

You would then repeat this for each line / substitution you need to make.

Comment: But I have about 400 lines in that file. Do you think there is a way of doing it quickly?

Comment: You did not originally specify the number of lines and the performance requirements so you received a general solution. You can try benchmarking it, 400 lines is really a trivial amount of content. Or maybe for flexibility you drop into a programming language solution and use XPath parsing to do the work.